# Passing a dataframe as train data and multiple columns of dataframe as train labels to a machine learning prediction model

Tags: python, dictionary, machine-learning, prediction, machine-learning-model

I have a dataframe like the following:

```
BankNum | FirstName | LastName  | ID |

00987772  |  Michael  | Brown   | 123 |
00987772  |  Bob      | Brown   | 123 |
00987772  |  Michael  | Mooney  | 123 |
00987772  |  Raven    | Mallik  | 245 |
00982122  |  Karim    | Hareche | 564 |
```

I am doing the following to get two dictionaries:

```
cols = [
    {'col': 'BankNum', 'func': lambda x: x.value_counts().to_dict()},
    {'col': 'FirstName', 'func': pd.Series.nunique},
    {'col': 'LastName', 'func': pd.Series.nunique}]

    d = df.groupby('Transporter ID').apply(lambda x: tuple(c['func'](x[c['col']]) for c in cols)).to_dict()            

    cols1 = ['ID']
    df2 = df.groupby('BankNum').apply(lambda x: tuple(x[c].nunique() for c in cols1))
    d1 = df2.to_dict()
```

where

```
d ={ 123 : ({00987772: 3}, 2,2), 245: ({00987772: 1}, 1,1), 564: ({00982122: 1}, 1,1)}

d1 = {00987772: (2,), 00982122:(1,)}
```

Next, I'm doing the following (below is just the relevant code, there are other things also that I'm doing which I've removed from the code below:

```
   same_banknum={}
   l=[] 
    w=[]
    m = v[2].values()
    h2 = sum(i > 6 for i in m)
    mod2 = sum(i in [5,6] for i in m)
    l2 = sum(i in [3,4] for i in m)
    if h2 != 0:
        for k2, v2 in v[2].items():
            if v2 > 6:
                l.append(k2)
                w.append(v2)



    new_l=[]
    for i in l:
        v3 = d1.get(i) 
        new_l.append(v3[0])

    h3 = sum(i > 8 for i in new_l)
    m3 = sum(i in [5,6,7,8] for i in new_l)
    l3 = sum(i in [3,4] for i in new_l)
    c=[]
    if h3 != 0:
        for g in new_l:
            if g > 8:
                c.append(g)
        wt = sum(c)
        same_banknum[k]= ("High", wt)
    elif m3 != 0:
        for g in new_l:
            if g in [5,6,7,8]:
                c.append(g)
        wt = sum(c)
        same_banknum[k]= ("Moderate", wt)
    elif l3 != 0:
        for g in new_l:
            if g in [3,4]:
                c.append(g)
        wt = sum(c)
        same_banknum[k]= ("Low", wt)
    else:
        same_banknum[k]= ("Low", 0.0)

elif mod2 != 0:
    for k2, v2 in v[2].items():
        if v2 in [5,6]:
            l.append(k2)
            w.append(v2)

    new_l=[]
    for i in l:
        v3 = d1.get(i) 
        new_l.append(v3[0])

    h3 = sum(i > 8 for i in new_l)
    m3 = sum(i in [5,6,7,8] for i in new_l)
    l3 = sum(i in [3,4] for i in new_l)
    c=[]
    if h3 != 0:
        for g in new_l:
            if g > 8:
                c.append(g)
        wt = sum(c)
        same_banknum[k]= ("High", wt)
    elif m3 != 0:
        for g in new_l:
            if g in [5,6,7,8]:
                c.append(g)
        wt = sum(c)
        same_banknum[k]= ("Moderate", wt)
    elif l3 != 0:
        for g in new_l:
            if g in [3,4]:
                c.append(g)
        wt = sum(c)
        same_banknum[k]= ("Low", wt)
    else:
        same_banknum[k]= ("Low", 0.0)
elif l2 != 0:
    for k2, v2 in v[2].items():
        if v2 in [3,4]:
            l.append(k2)
            w.append(v2)

    new_l=[]
    for i in l:
        v3 = d1.get(i) 
        new_l.append(v3[0])

    h3 = sum(i > 8 for i in new_l)
    m3 = sum(i in [5,6,7,8] for i in new_l)
    l3 = sum(i in [3,4] for i in new_l)
    c=[]
    if h3 != 0:
        for g in new_l:
            if g > 8:
                c.append(g)
        wt = sum(c)
        same_banknum[k]= ("High", wt)
    elif m3 != 0:
        for g in new_l:
            if g in [5,6,7,8]:
                c.append(g)
        wt = sum(c)
        same_banknum[k]= ("Moderate", wt)
    elif l3 != 0:
        for g in new_l:
            if g in [3,4]:
                c.append(g)
        wt = sum(c)
        same_banknum[k]= ("Low", wt)
    else:
        same_banknum[k]= ("Low", 0.0)
else:
    for k2, v2 in v[2].items():
        if v2 in [1,2]:
            l.append(k2)

    new_l=[]
    for i in l:
        v3 = d1.get(i) 
        new_l.append(v3[0])

    h3 = sum(i > 8 for i in new_l)
    m3 = sum(i in [5,6,7,8] for i in new_l)
    l3 = sum(i in [3,4] for i in new_l)
    c=[]
    if h3 != 0:
        for g in new_l:
            if g > 8:
                c.append(g)
        wt = sum(c)
        same_banknum[k]= ("High", wt)
    elif m3 != 0:
        for g in new_l:
            if g in [5,6,7,8]:
                c.append(g)
        wt = sum(c)
        same_banknum[k]= ("Moderate", wt)
    elif l3 != 0:
        for g in new_l:
            if g in [3,4]:
                c.append(g)
        wt = sum(c)
        same_banknum[k]= ("Low", wt)
    else:
        same_banknum[k]= ("Low", 0.0)
```

to get a dictionary like this:

```
same_banknum = {123: ('Low', 0.6), 245: ('Low', 0.6), 564: ('Low', 0.0)}
```

The same_banknum dictionary performs the above computation and finds out if same `BankNum` exists for multiple IDs and then assigns them `High`, `Low`, `Moderate` value along with the weight of it being true to it, to give us a dictionary.

Which I can convert to a dataframe like following:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(same_banknum, orient='index').reset_index()
df1.columns = ['ID','SameBankNum_Val','SameBankNum_Wt']
```

which gives:

```
ID   | SameBankNum_Val  | SameBankNum_Wt
123  |  Low             | 0.6
245  | Low              | 0.6
564  | Low              | 0.0
```

What I want to do is that instead of performing this computation again and again for each new dataset that comes in, I want to use Machine Learning to build a predictive model, that predicts the above `SameBankNum_Val` & `SameBankNum_Wt` for the new IDs (test data).

I could add the `SameBankNum_Val` & the `SameBankNum_Wt` columns to the above training dataframe. But, what I want to know is:
**How do I pass multiple columns (`BankNum`, `FirstName`, `LastName`, `ID`) (from Dataframe 1 from above) as the train data and multiple columns (`SameBankNum_Val`, `SameBankNum_Wt`)  (from Dataframe 2 above) as the train label in a machine learning model?**

Also, will the machine learning model be accurate enough as to when to give it `High`, `Low` or `Moderate` value and what weight without performing that long computation again and again? For this question, I guess I'll just have to test with multiple models first.

Please help! Thanks!